# Is there an ncurses tool for upstart similar to ntsysv or sysv-rc-conf?

Tags: upstart, runlevel, ncurses

I'd like to be able to use a terminal or console to configure runlevels.  I don't need the conditions for starting and stopping services to be any more complicated than sysv.  I just want to base decisions on the runlevel.